# Changing the exhaust on a motorbike

Tags: motorcycle, exhaust, yamaha

I have a Yamaha XJ6 from 2012 and I would like to change the exhaust.
But I have a choice.

Do I change only the muffler or the whole "line"?

Other than cost what are the pros and cons of changing the muffler vs. the whole line?

Comment: You have to look at two things: money and goal. These two things come up all the time when deciding what to do with a vehicle. Figure out your goal, then how much money you want to spend. It will make this a whole lot easier to make decisions.

Comment: Thank you Paulster, for the goal the idea is to make more noise in order to warn car drivers that I am here. The Butget in tiself would be between 500 and 800 euros.

Comment: Take a look at this [forum](http://www.600cc.org/forum/f101/xj6-aftermarket-exhaust-24072/) ... they have a whole list of aftermarket exhausts for the XJ6.

Comment: Thank you, but what are the pros and cons of both solutions?

Comment: A full system may require you to have your carbs recalibrated slightly to take advantage of the higher exhaust flow rate (someone tell me if I'm smoking something). If you're just after noise, just get a new muffler. Full systems are really only for when you want a little extra power.

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for! If you want to put it as an answer so i can validate it. Thank you!

Comment: @Strauss: Isn't that bike fuel injected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2012 XJ6 is fuel injected, so an aftermarket exhaust (Arrows, Leo Vince, Scorpion, Two Brothers, Akrapovic etc) would be easily procured. You may even get good deals on used slip-on exhausts, and you could then re-pack the glass wool (other as applicable) if required.

In order to keep the cost down, you could opt for a slip-on exhaust (muffler) instead of a full-system ("whole line"). In either case, some performance benefits and varying levels of exhaust note changes will be obtained. In either case, significant weight reduction is possible. In my case, the stock exhaust was 11 kilos, while my aftermarket full system was under 3.5 kilos.

The stock maps that come tuned for the stock exhaust may not allow you to extract all that the aftermarket exhaust could give. For this, a piggy-back module like the Dynojet Power Commander, or Bazzaz units that allow you to load a different (read richer) map will help with the gain in performance you would desire. In addition, such units allow you to get rid of flat spots in the stock map, to keep the power delivery linear over the rev-range.

There are other options like Tuneboy and Flashtune that remap the stock ECU instead of requiring a piggy-back unit. However, these may void your warranty.

Please be aware that certain cities have regulations that govern the permitted sound level for exhausts. Most exhausts come with baffles that reduce the sound output to an extent. Please check the regulations in your area of use before you pull the trigger.

happy riding!

Comment: Wow, that was an awesome answer, thank you very much!
Exactly the kind of informations I was looking for.

Comment: Happy to be useful! Feel free to reach out anytime.

Comment: @Shrinivas, you forgot yoshi.. ;) and yes, a a stock map will not allow to unlock its full potential. But still, the ecu varies the timing and AFR ratio to some extend to cope up with the sudden change/ free flowing of the exhaust gas through the outlet manifold. And btw, which bike do you ride?? Curiosity..

Comment: @You_Shall_Not_Pass, I ride a 2012 Ninja 650 primarily. Running a full system Leo Vince Underbody Evo II exhaust, Power commander 5 and custom maps. You?

Comment: @Shrinivas i was not entirely correct when i said that the ecu can cause slight changes to itself. Apparently only vehicles which has an O2 sensor can do that. Changing to a free flow exhaust or high flow air filter could expose your ride to the risk of running lean unless tuned or remapped about which you have already given a near-perfect explanation above. And Grats on the ride. Excellent choice and selection. A man's gotta love the LeoV :D I ride a Royal Enfield Classic 350 and a Suzuki Samurai 100cc 2 Stroke (which very badly need a rebuilding)